# Error running C:/PROGRA~1/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/xelatex.exe (exit code -1073740791)

Tags: latex

Tengo el siguiente problema al compilar un pdf a través de Sweave en RStudio. Me gustaría que el documento compile sin errores.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hola mundo!


\end{document}
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
output file: x1.tex

[1] "x1.tex"
Running xelatex.exe on x1.tex...failed
Error running C:/PROGRA~1/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/xelatex.exe (exit code -1073740791)
```

No se si tenga algo que ver con la nueva actualización de R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)

Comment: Puede que tengas varias instalaciones de LaTeX en tu equipo y que R no esté apuntando a la instlación correcta ¿? Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33650869/5587982) y sus respuestas.

Comment: Ese código es normalmente un file system error. Es posible que no tengas permisos para modificar/generar algún archivo. Revisa el visor de eventos en windows o las notificaciones de Win10 sobre intentos de modificación a carpetas controladas (no sé dónde estés intentando generar el resultado; si es en MisDocumentos, puede fallar por esto)

Comment: Gracias estimados por ayudarme a resolver este problema. Intenté todo lo que me recomendaron, pero al final lo logré desinstalando MiKTeX, luego borrar todos los archivos residuales. Al volver instalar seguí los pasos de este link https://yihui.org/en/2018/03/miktex-auto-install/

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario volver a instalar el MiKTeX, luego de desinstalar hay que eliminar todos los archivos residuales y al ejecutar nuevamente el .exe seguir los pasos de este link https://yihui.org/en/2018/03/miktex-auto-install/